# `term` often gets filled with random character codes, any suggestion on how to fix it?

Tags: debugging, term

I'm running doom emacs, and here's an example of a command I ran and the resulting output. For some reason, `term` gets filled with these random character codes. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: have started using `vterm`, which doesn't seem to have this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, any escape sequences of the form `ESC ]...` are [OSC (Operating System Command) sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC), and support varies fairly widely.

(For instance, https://github.com/Alhadis/OSC8-Adoption is a repository someone made in order to track support for a sequence for embedding hyperlinks in terminal output.)

FWIW comint (and hence `M-x shell`) can support some of these (OSCs 2,7,8 in Emacs 29.1) if you add `comint-osc-process-output` to `comint-output-filter-functions`; but I believe `M-x term` has no equivalent support at present.

Your case is mostly OSC 4, and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139645 seems as good an explanation as I've managed to find.

You *might* find that the program you're running has some options or config to tell it *not* to spit out this stuff, as it's not supported everywhere.  (If not, you could raise a bug report with them.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!